# UnitySocketIO sending a websocket message to nodejs

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, unity-game-engine, socket.io

Just wondering if anyone has used the UnitySocketIO to chat between unity and node.js.

I want to send a message but the documentation is lacking and everyone has a different way of doing it without explaining key aspects to setting it up.

In Unity(C#) i set it up like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using SocketIOClient;

public class Gui : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnGUI () {
        // Make a background box
        GUI.Box(new Rect(10,10,100,90), "Loader Menu");

        // Make the first button. If it is pressed, Application.Loadlevel (1) will be executed
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(20,40,80,20), "Level 1")) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Button 1");
        }
        // Make the second button.
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(20,70,80,20), "Socket test")) 
        {
            string socketUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8001";
            Debug.Log("socket url: " + socketUrl);
            Client client = new Client(socketUrl);
            client.Send("Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

My node server is set up like this to recieve the message:

```
io.sockets.on("connect", function(socket)
{
    socket.on("Hey", function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Im not sure how it works I tried to iplement the "Hey" into the send in unity as I would with any other client but it does not allow multiple parameters.
Any insight would be great!!

Comment: Ever figure this out?  I'm trying to implement the same thing.

Comment: @Harrison I got it to work from game to server but not back from server to unity. I have files I can send you if you wish would love to try make it work

Comment: That would be great!  I am still trying to get the Client to connect properly so any code would be very helpful.  Do you have it on a gist or something?

Comment: sorry about the delay the link is https://github.com/DennisKilleen/NodeUnityTest ive left my email in the readme so if you have any questions send them to me an ill get back to you. also if you make it work can you update the repo as this will help everyone else who looks here @Harrison

Answer (score 0):

That used to work with Socket.io 0.9.x but have not try with 1.x.
Try listening for the 'message' event on the server side.

```
io.sockets.on("connect", function(socket)
{
    socket.on("message", function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

And you should see the word *'Hey'* somewhere in the *data*.